# Accessing key of MultiIndexed groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas groupby object, from two keys.

```
gb = df.groupby(['A','B'])
```

How can I access a specific key say `(2,4)`, how do I do it?
*The `group_by()` method works well if there is only one key.*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `get_group`:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[2, 4, 1], [2, 4, 2], [3, 4, 1]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
   A  B  C
0  2  4  1
1  2  4  2
2  3  4  1

In [3]: g = df.groupby(['A', 'B'])

In [4]: g.get_group((2,4))
Out[4]:
   A  B  C
0  2  4  1
1  2  4  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a tuple in `get_group`

```
In [49]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randint(10,size=15).reshape(5,3),columns=list('ABC'))

In [50]: df
Out[50]: 
   A  B  C
0  8  9  2
1  7  5  3
2  3  1  2
3  2  4  0
4  6  9  4

In [51]: df.groupby(['A','B']).sum()
Out[51]: 
     C
A B   
2 4  0
3 1  2
6 9  4
7 5  3
8 9  2

In [52]: df.groupby(['A','B']).get_group((6,9))
Out[52]: 
   A  B  C
4  6  9  4
```